# Need help Proving that If $D=P^{-1}AP$ then $A^m = PD^mP^{-1}.$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, induction, diagonalization

The question is in the title, all the above are relevant to Matrices and P is a invertable matrix. Also D would refer to the diagonal matrix and P is a matrix with eigenvectors as it's column entries.

Comment: **Hint:** I added the (induction) tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$
\begin{align}D=P^{-1}AP&\iff A=PDP^{-1}\\
A=PDP^{-1} &\implies A^2= PD\color{red}{P^{-1}P}DP^{-1}=PD^2P^{-1}\\
A=PDP^{-1} &\implies A^3= A^2A=PD^2\color{red}{P^{-1}P}DP^{-1}=PD^3P^{-1}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This argument and induction will  easily bring you to the solution